# Eureka,Zuul,Microservices and Spring Security concern

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, netflix-eureka

I've used eureka and zuul proxy to implement jwt validation for a few microservices.Basically, the frontend now sends it's requests to the proxy where the token will get validated and if it's ok then it will forward the request to the specific microservice.My concern is that all of those microservices don't have any type of security so anyone could easily call their endpoints without any problems.
What would be the best solution here? are there ways to accept requests only coming from the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Proper setup of CORS does the job

[Link to the Spring boot CORS setup guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: I'll look into it! Thanks!